# TCL: How to convert a very long string into ASCII in TCL

Tags: string, char, format, tcl, ascii

I am trying to convert a very long string into ASCII hex.

How can I go about doing this?

I've written this really long switch statement, but I know there is a much simpler way of doing this. I am having problems with all the odd symbols like brackets, #, $, \, etc... in the switch statement. I can get some to work with a backslash in from of them but others fail.

```
proc Text_to_ASCII {string} {

set Ascii_Word ""

set stringLength [string length $string]

for {set i 0} {$i < $stringLength} {incr i} {

    set Letter [string index $string $i]

    switch -glob $Letter {

        " "     {set hex_ascii 20}

        0   {set hex_ascii 30}
        1   {set hex_ascii 31}
        2   {set hex_ascii 32}
        3   {set hex_ascii 33}
        4   {set hex_ascii 34}
        5   {set hex_ascii 35}
        6   {set hex_ascii 36}
        7   {set hex_ascii 37}
        8   {set hex_ascii 38}
        9   {set hex_ascii 39}

        A   {set hex_ascii 41}
        B   {set hex_ascii 42}
        C   {set hex_ascii 43}
        D   {set hex_ascii 44}
        E   {set hex_ascii 45}
        F   {set hex_ascii 46}
        G   {set hex_ascii 47}
        H   {set hex_ascii 48}
        I   {set hex_ascii 49}
        J   {set hex_ascii 4A}
        K   {set hex_ascii 4B}
        L   {set hex_ascii 4C}
        M   {set hex_ascii 4D}
        N   {set hex_ascii 4E}
        O   {set hex_ascii 4F}
        P   {set hex_ascii 50}
        Q   {set hex_ascii 51}
        R   {set hex_ascii 52}
        S   {set hex_ascii 53}
        T   {set hex_ascii 54}
        U   {set hex_ascii 55}
        V   {set hex_ascii 56}
        W   {set hex_ascii 57}
        X   {set hex_ascii 58}
        Y   {set hex_ascii 59}
        Z   {set hex_ascii 5A}

        a   {set hex_ascii 61}
        b   {set hex_ascii 62}
        c   {set hex_ascii 63}
        d   {set hex_ascii 64}
        e   {set hex_ascii 65}
        g   {set hex_ascii 67}
        h   {set hex_ascii 68}
        i   {set hex_ascii 69}
        j   {set hex_ascii 6A}
        k   {set hex_ascii 6B}
        l   {set hex_ascii 6C}
        m   {set hex_ascii 6D}
        n   {set hex_ascii 6E}
        o   {set hex_ascii 6F}
        p   {set hex_ascii 70}
        q   {set hex_ascii 71}
        r   {set hex_ascii 72}
        s   {set hex_ascii 73}
        t   {set hex_ascii 74}
        u   {set hex_ascii 75}
        v   {set hex_ascii 76}
        w   {set hex_ascii 77}
        x   {set hex_ascii 78}
        y   {set hex_ascii 79}
        z   {set hex_ascii 7A}


        default {set hex_ascii 3F}
    }

append Ascii_Word $hex_ascii

}

return $Ascii_Word
}
```

So I have been trying this code out...

```
proc string2hex {s} {
binary scan $s H* hex
regsub -all (..) $hex {\\x\1}
}

set input_string "lol"

set ascii_string [string2hex $input_string]
```

which returns "\x6c\x6f\x6c"
Which is super close to what I want which is "6c6f6c"
How do I drop the \x? I was thinking of just doing trimleft twice to get rid of \x for each character and maybe just feed this thing one character at a time...

thoughts???

Comment: How do you define this conversion? Do you want a string with only 7-bit characters? What should happen to characters that aren't in the ASCII set? What kind of characters do you expect to get as input?

Comment: only 7 bit characters that can be typed on a keyboard.

I need to convert written word into ASCII. The software I'm using will only take a ASCII input.

"Convert me to ASCII" is a perfect example of what it will be fed.

I considered just manually scanning through each letter in a for loop, then using a switch statement with char to ascii conversions, and then stitching it all together as I go, but I'm guessing there is a very simple way to do this in tcl using the [format]  call, but I am not super knowledgeable in tcl and can't figure it out.

Comment: None of the code below works in anyway close to what I am accomplishing

If I input a "?" into the proc string to ascii, I would expect a value of 3F to be returned. I don't know if you call that the unicode value or what.

Comment: what I'm trying to get to...

UTF-8 is a method of transforming all Unicode characters into a variable length encoding of bytes; a single Unicode character can be represented by one, two, or three bytes. The advantage of the UTF-8 standard is that it and the Unicode standard were designed so that Unicode characters corresponding to the standard ASCII set (up to ASCII value 0x7F in hexadecimal) have the same byte values in both UTF-8 and ASCII encoding. In other words, an upper-case "A" character is represented by the single-byte value 0x41 in both UTF-8 and ASCII encoding.

Comment: I've added a couple of suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what exactly you mean. Do you mean really “convert this string to ASCII codes and replace unknown characters with `?`” (or some other character) or do you mean “get the Unicode character codes for all the characters in this string”? The second one is perhaps the most likely:

```
proc string_to_ascii {string_value} {
    return [lmap c [split $string_value ""] {
        scan $c %c code
        # Make the code the result of this inner script
        string cat $code
    }]
}
```

This isn't the most efficient version of that. For long strings, it turns out that it is a *huge* win to do this longer version:

```
proc string_to_ascii {string_value} {
    set map {}
    set result [lrepeat [string length $string_value] DUMMY]
    set idx 0
    foreach c [split $string_value ""] {
        if {![dict exists $map $c]} {
            scan $c %c ch
            dict set map $c $ch
        }
        lset result $idx [dict get $map $c]
        incr idx
    }
    return $result
}
```

This is a win for two reasons:

1. It preallocates the result list. This isn't essential as Tcl's lists do use an amortised exponential growth strategy for managing their backing C arrays, but we know the length we're going to get so we can get smarter.
2. It shares the integer objects (yes, *of course* Tcl has these things; it's just that Tcl's type system usually conspires to make you not need to worry about it) so that the number of memory allocations is greatly reduced. This is effectively the same strategy that the `split` command uses when splitting into characters (and `binary scan` does as well) and is a really colossal performance win even with even surprisingly short strings.

But it's all rather more complicated. Use the first version (or a simple `split $str {}` if you don't really need the codepoints immediately) as that's much easier to write and pretty well optimised internally.

---

For forcing a string to be just ASCII, you can do:

```
encoding convertto ascii $input_string
```

The result is *technically* a byte-array, but works just fine as an ASCII string. If you instead want to *detect* non-ASCII (e.g., so you can complain about it) then you instead use `string is ascii`:

```
if {![string is ascii -failindex idx $input_string]} {
    error "found non-ASCII char at index $idx \"[string index $input_string $idx]\""
}
```

If you don't care where the bad character is, a simple `string is ascii $input_string` will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for something like

```
binary format a* [encoding convertto ascii $string_value]
```

The result certainly looks like ASCII to me, even though I can't be sure this is what you're after.

**Update:** I'm still a bit confused about what the desired goal is and why none of the existing answers are useful. If none of the characters in the expected input are outside the ASCII range, A UTF-8 string is identical to an ASCII one: there is nothing to convert.

If there *are* non-ASCII characters: a conversion is useful:

```
% encoding convertto ascii abcåäö
abc???
```

The result is a UTF-8 / ASCII string.

If simply taking the low byte of each character in the string and masking each one to 7-bit is desired:

```
% join [lmap c [split [binary format a* abcåäö] {}] {format %c [expr {[scan $c %c] & 0x7f}]}] {}
abcedv
```

If you want to get hex codes from a string:

```
% binary encode hex abcåäö
616263e5e4f6
```

In this case, no conversion is made (which of course works if input is already just ASCII): combine with other methods to get pure ASCII, like:

```
% binary encode hex [encoding convertto ascii abcåäö]
6162633f3f3f
```

Documentation:
[binary](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/binary.htm),
[encoding](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/encoding.htm)

Comment: If I input a question mark, I want to get 3F as a return value.

If I input a space, I want to get 20 as a return value.

I think I'm misusing the term ascii and maybe a couple others. 

Let me try what you've suggested and see if that works:)

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use the `encoding` command to convert from one encoding to another. A example would be:

```
% encoding convertto ascii "Yen ¥ symbol is not ascii, $ is, and © Copyright also is not."
--> Yen ? symbol is not ascii, $ is, and ? Copyright also is not.
```

If this does not work for you take a look at the `string is ascii` command.